# use ActiveControl to get rid of long lines of Else if code

Tags: vb.net

I am aware there are many posts on this topic but none of them fit my case.  I have a Form1 with a TabControl1 with 10 tabs. On 8 of the tabs I have a UserControl. The UserControls by default are numbered UserControl110, UserControl111,..UserControl117. I use a KeyDown event in Form1 code which starts a Sub Routine in the UserControl Class Code. For example UserControl110.myPrint() works as expected. By using many lines of Else If code (see below) I get the correct UserControl to complete the Sub Routine. I would think you could use ActiveControl to get the correct UserControl and dot it with myPrint() and eliminate the many lines of Else If code but what I have tried doesn't work. Manybe some LINQ code would work also but I am very new with LINQ.

This code works...

```
        If UserControl110.Visible = True Then
            UserControl110.myPrint()
        ElseIf UserControl111.Visible = True Then
            UserControl111.myPrint()
        ElseIf UserControl112.Visible = True Then
            UserControl112.myPrint()
        ElseIf UserControl113.Visible = True Then
            UserControl113.myPrint()
        ElseIf UserControl114.Visible = True Then
            UserControl114.myPrint()
        ElseIf UserControl115.Visible = True Then
            UserControl115.myPrint()
        ElseIf UserControl116.Visible = True Then
            UserControl116.myPrint()
        ElseIf UserControl117.Visible = True Then
            UserControl117.myPrint()
        End If
```

But this does not

```
        Dim Ctrl As Control = Me.ActiveControl
             Ctrl.myPrint()
```

I have shown the code above that works and doesn't work.

I am hoping that the 2 or maybe 3 lines of code would replace the many Else If lines of code.

Comment: You should always describe what "doesn't work" mean.  UserControls are container controls, so they usually can never have the focus, or be "active".  Are all of the UserControls the same type?

Comment: All user controls are identical. They each fill the entire page of a TabControl. Each UserControl contains an 11 column DataGridView, 5 Textboxes, 6 Labels, 8 Buttons and nearly 400 lines of code in the UserControl1 Class. Each UserControl receives slightly different data. The code Dim Ctrl As Control = Me.ActiveControl followed by MessageBox.Show(Ctrl.Name)  does provide the UserControl name, e.g., UserControl110 but Inserting the variable Ctrl or Ctrl.Name doesn't work. Perhaps the Ctrl needs to have a data type conversion but I tried a few different types and that didn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the code to read:

```
Public Sub PKey_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles MyBase.KeyDown
    If e.KeyData = (Keys.Control Or Keys.P) Then
        Dim Ctrl As Object = Me.ActiveControl
        Ctrl.myPrint()
    End If
End Sub
```

And it works perfectly. Reduced 20 lines of Else If code. Called Ctrl an Object instead of a Control.

Comment: You should check to see if Ctrl is not null and a type that has a myPrint method.  Instead of object, you would use a cast `DirectCast(Ctrl, UserCtrl).myPrint()`

Comment: Thanks for the advice, your code works but I don't know what trouble I can get into using Object. Could you explain. With all the hassle of trying to use printer code in the UserControl Class it is almost easier to write duplicate printer code in the Form1 Class..